# how to get datagridview.rows().columns().style.backcolor to work in cellvalidating?

Tags: datagridview

I have a datagridview in which I paint in green the cell on entering and in white while endediting. I need to change the color of the cell to red if an error is trapped in cell validating. The last part i.e painting in red in cell validating seems not to work.
Here is the suspected code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView4_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView4.CellValidating

    ' check if the quantity is valid
    Dim Str_Input As String = CStr(e.FormattedValue)
    Dim Str_ColumnName As String = DataGridView4.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).OwningColumn.Name

    If Str_ColumnName = "quantity" Then

        If Not (IsNumeric(Str_Input)) Then

            DataGridView4.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView4.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
            e.Cancel = True

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: We will need to see the code that does not work to help you figure out why it does not work. Please provide the code that is not working as you expect.

Comment: Well… It is unclear how the grid is filled with data? What “type” of column is the `quantity` column? Is it a numeric type or a `string` type? The code appears to work if the column type is a `string` type. However, it should be noted that IF a cell is colored “Red”, then it will remain red even if the cells value becomes valid. You need an “Else” clause to color the cell to “White” if the value IS valid. Also "why" is code calling `e.Cancel = True` if the cells value is not numeric?